# UIScrollView in UITableViewCell keeps reloading as table is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm coming close to the end of development on a very substantial pet project that I've been putting off for years, and I've got an even *more* substantial problem that I've run into with an added bit of functionality.

Within this app, I have a UITableView that has a custom cell with a UIScrollView. Inside this scroll view, I dynamically populate it with the contents of an array. Though I got this working perfectly (ish), it came with an unexpected side effect: **Whenever the table is scrolled, the UIScrollViews don't refresh as I'd expect them to, and generate more UILabels within themselves.**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llxbv.jpg) you can see the UITableViewCell with the UIScrollViews, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKaXg.jpg) you can see what happens after just one scroll through the table. It goes without saying, but more scrolling leads to a worsened effect, and eventually the memory use becomes unsustainable and the UX is... well, it just isn't anything I'd call an *experience*.

The offending code is below, and it's in the *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:* method.

```
int stopCount = (int)[[busStop valueForKey:@"Stop Times"] count];
int horizontalSpacing = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stopCount; i++) {
    UILabel *timeLabel;
    if (!timeLabel) {
        timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(horizontalSpacing, 0, 75, 20)];
        timeLabel.text = [[busStop valueForKey:@"Stop Times"] objectAtIndex:i];
        timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0];
        horizontalSpacing += timeLabel.bounds.size.width;
        [cell.stopTimesView addSubview:timeLabel];
    }
}
cell.stopTimesView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(horizontalSpacing, 20);
```

I'm suspecting that this is neither the time nor the place to be populating the scroll view, but I'm stuck as to where a more appropriate place to put it would be (perhaps the custom cell class methods?).

I greatly appreciate any and all assistance that anyone could provide on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you got is not suprising because you keep adding new `UILabel`s to the `UIScrollView` in each cell without deleting the old ones first. Clear the content of the `UIScrollView` before adding new labels into it by doing something like this

```
[cell.stopTimesView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]
```

Also, I don't see the point of the code below:

```
UILabel *timeLabel;
if (!timeLabel)
```

Since you have defined `timeLabel` in the line above, it clearly will have the value of `nil`, and hence the `if` statement is unnecessary.

So your final code should be like this:

```
int stopCount = (int)[[busStop valueForKey:@"Stop Times"] count];
int horizontalSpacing = 0;

[cell.stopTimesView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

for (int i = 0; i < stopCount; i++) {
    UILabel *timeLabel = timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(horizontalSpacing, 0, 75, 20)];
    timeLabel.text = [[busStop valueForKey:@"Stop Times"] objectAtIndex:i];
    timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0];
    horizontalSpacing += timeLabel.bounds.size.width;
    [cell.stopTimesView addSubview:timeLabel];
}
cell.stopTimesView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(horizontalSpacing, 20);
```

Comment: Outstanding, that worked like a charm. And understood on the UILabel if statement, it was a last-ditch (and very half-hearted) attempt at solving the issue.